# Cloudsim multiple datacenters

Tags: parallel-processing, cloud, simulation, distributed-computing, cloudsim

Holo
I'm working on Cloudsim simulator and I'm trying to create two datacenters and run only 1 cloudlet on them but I don't know if it's even possible to do that.
I can't find any information on internet.

Thanks for helping !

Answer (score 0):

If you want two datacenters, you just need to instantiate them in the same way you instantiate the first one. Each Datacenter you instantiate is automatically assigned to your simulation.

But if you want to use a modern, full-featured, state-of-the-art and easier-to-use fork of CloudSim, try [CloudSim Plus](http://cloudsimplus.org).

Comment: Okay thanks, I resolved the problem of datacenter in other way.. but not the running cloudlet. 
What I'm trying to do is to get the required files of some cloudlet : for example cloudlet0 (running on dc0) needs F1 and F2 to be executed. 
- F1 is available locally so no problem, but F2 is stored in dc1, so i want to move the cloudlet to that dc1 to continue its execution. Is that possible to do ? if yes would you help me. thanks !

Comment: You don't have how to migrate a Cloudlet. This doesn't even work in real world because apps have configurations and dependencies that you don't have how to find out in an autonomous way. You can just migrate containers and VMs, since they encapsulate everything the app needs. CloudSim has a container module, but it's buggy. Anyway, you can migrate the VMs to the DC where the files you need are.

CloudSim Plus has some related critical issues fixed, such as: [#132](https://github.com/manoelcampos/cloudsim-plus/issues/132), [#138](https://github.com/manoelcampos/cloudsim-plus/issues/138)